# Short of running one's own node, how can I see the code of suicided contracts?

Tags: selfdestruct, bytecode

I'm interested in looking at the code in instances of the Parity Multisig wallet attacks, but the contracts have self-destructed. How can I get ahold of the exact bytecode that was executed in a given transaction once the contract has self-destructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the source code, you can check Parity's repo. To get the bytecode, do something like:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/"));
const deadContractAddress = "0x863DF6BFa4469f3ead0bE8f9F2AAE51c91A907b4";
const blockAtDestruct = 4501969;
const blockBeforeDestruct = blockAtDestruct - 1;

web3.eth.getCode(
    deadContractAddress,
    blockBeforeDestruct,
    console.log);
```